This question gets 10k+ views per day but no interactions
How to use DataFrameMapper to delete rows with column[xxx] val is null?, which was asked 11 days ago, has an astonishingly high number of views, 113k. That amounts to more than 10k views per day.
There are no comments, answers, votes or even edits. It has three tags; two tiny (fewer than 20 questions) and one small (more than 1k questions).
I'm no expert on the topic, but it seems just like a normal "how-to" question. What could be the cause of this?

I would assume it's due to the three repeating letters in the title, given how high that term tends to trend daily

Related on MSE? Why does my question get this many views?

It's self-evidently the "xxx" in the title. That's been a massive search term since basically the beginning of the internet (and well before).

It probably the 3x. Another question with 3x with 299k views in 29 days. There are more of these if you search for them.

Well, now I know how to speed run the "famous question" badge...

Another thing to note is that not all "xxx"-titled questions get (that) many views: views:0..1000 title:"xxx" created:2022..2025: 454 results vs. view:1000 ...: 142 results.

general SEDE query for things with high average view count per day of existence: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1853159

Funny things: having xxxx doesn't help as showed here, only 3 is relevant. (note: I was searching for this post, I knew I posted a comment but impossible to find it, and it's normal as it seems removed...)

A reason is the xxx in the title, I had the same issue already:
Why does my question get this many views?
But I think there are specific conditions that accelerate the view count in this case:

Python + Machine learning is already a popular topic. So the question will have some genuine interest also, giving it more prominence for bots, too.
My guess is that column could well fit a search pattern like c*m, which might be searched for in the xxx context

Case comparison:

I suspect that my own answer triggered the phenomena due
to the combination of xxx and machine
It was definitely due to the title, because:

The tag I posted on has 10s of views on average
Renaming xxx to foo instantly stopped the flood of views




I'm not sure why column could well fit a search pattern like c*m? Its last character is n, not m, and I think the person who query the latter will spell it explicitly

I believe this happens specifically because of Google "Safe Search" being on by default, so that any non porn page on a large website with XXX on it gets massive hits. The same happens e.g. on Wikipedia: https://pageviews.wmcloud.org/topviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&date=2023-08&excludes=

Not sure about the exact influence of the "connected" words. What I can say is: most of the questions that really take off, either use the term xxx a lot in the title or have some words in there that are no mentioned often in question titles. E.g. machine, parent or column. Though the column is a bit far fetched, you are right.
